# How to Work Around this Annoying Matlab Rounding Error

Tags: matlab, rounding-error

I need a workaround for this issue. An explanation of why this is ONLY happening to one number would also be very helpful as I'd like to avoid this in the future. I've set the `format long` option to show what is happening.

I start by creating a vector. Just like this:

`>> vec = [0, 2.4, 2.8, 5.2, 5.6]`

It returns, as expected, this:

```
vec = 
0   2.400000000000000   2.800000000000000   5.200000000000000   5.600000000000000
```

Now, I want to add 0.4 to all of these:

`>> vec + 0.4`

But, here is my output:

```
ans =
0.400000000000000   2.800000000000000   3.200000000000000   5.600000000000001   6.000000000000000
```

Notice the rounding error on 5.6. It shouldn't have that 1. I tried using `vec + round(0.4,1)` but that also does not work.

Why does this only happen to 5.6? How can I avoid this? If it is unavoidable, how can I work around it?

EDIT: Also, in case this is useful.

MATLAB Version: 8.6.0.267246 (R2015b)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise  Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: What exactly is "working around it" supposed to mean? This is how numbers are stored in computer memory.

Comment: @excaza - Sure, so how do you work around the fact that you can't store 5.6 exactly?

Comment: I know where rounding errors come from. I just don't expect software like Matlab to have this issue. This breaks a lot of very simple code.

A specific workaround in Matlab would be helpful. Oliver I'll look into that website you posted.

Comment: The reason I need a work around is because I store `vec` and `vec4 = vec + 0.4` as two separate vectors. Then, I compare them with `vec==vec4`. I expect to get a logical array that tells me where numbers are equivalent so I can remove them. But this error means that the entire rest of my code cannot work unless I can find a workaround.

Comment: You should basically never test for exact equality with respect to floating point values. Always test for a difference to some tolerance. E.g., `abs(vec1-vec4)<1e-8` instead of `vec1==vec4`

Comment: The moral of this story is you **don't** compare for exact equality. You use a tolerance.  That's the crux of floating-point arithmetic.  See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: @toshiomagic *all* software has this problem